# How to use this VBA code to use as Public Subroutine in Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have got this code below that restricts users to leave an empty field in a form. Now I want to use this in all of my forms. I've tried to use in Public Subroutine using a module. But it doesn't work.

```vb
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

    Dim msg As String, Style As Integer, Title As String
    Dim nl As String, ctl As Control

    
    nl = vbNewLine & vbNewLine

    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
      If ctl.ControlType = acTextBox Then
        If ctl.Tag = "*" And Trim(ctl & "") = "" Then
         msg = "Data Required for '" & ctl.Name & "' field!" & nl & _
               "You can't save this record until this data is provided!" & nl & _
               "Enter the data and try again . . . "
          Style = vbCritical + vbOKOnly
          Title = "Required Data..."
          MsgBox msg, Style, Title
          ctl.SetFocus
          Cancel = True
          Exit For
        End If
      End If
    Next

End Sub
```

I just want to use this in all of my forms. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: And where is the code that "doesn't work"? What happens - error message, wrong result, nothing?

Comment: When I used in public sub it showed me an error "Invalid use of Me".

Comment: `Me` is only valid behind forms and reports. It is shorthand alias for the form/report name/object the code is associated with. Most likely you need to pass form name or the form object to public procedure and replace `Me` with that variable reference. The procedure needs to be a Function that returns a value to the BeforeUpdate event procedure so it can determine whether to Cancel the update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question, and good idea.

So, keep in mind that "me" is just the current form you are working with.

So, create a plane jane standard code module. And drop in your function like this with a "few" changes.

```
Public Function CheckRequired(MyMe As Form) As Boolean


  Dim msg        As String
  Dim Style      As Integer
  Dim Title      As String
  Dim nl         As String
  Dim ctl        As Control

  nl = vbCrLf             ' crlf gives you one line

  CheckRequired = False   ' assume everything ok
  
  For Each ctl In MyMe.Controls
    If ctl.ControlType = acTextBox Then
      If ctl.Tag = "*" And Trim(ctl & "") = "" Then
       msg = "Data Required for '" & ctl.Name & "' field!" & nl & _
             "You can't save this record until this data is provided!" & nl & _
             "Enter the data and try again . . . "
        Style = vbCritical + vbOKOnly
        Title = "Required Data..."
        MsgBox msg, Style, Title
        ctl.SetFocus
        CheckRequired = True
        Exit Function
      End If
    End If
  Next

End Function
```

Now, in the forms event (which has that cancel), then you do this:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
 
   Cancel = CheckRequired(Me)
 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

As @June7 mentioned, `Me` is only valid behind forms and reports. It is shorthand alias for the form/report name/object. To achieve what you are looking for, you can try this concept. Create the global routine like below :

```
Public Function Validate_BeforeUpdate(frm As Form) As Integer

    Dim msg As String, Style As Integer, Title As String
    Dim nl As String, ctl As Control
    

    nl = vbNewLine & vbNewLine

    For Each ctl In frm.Controls
      '''' your other code
      Validate_BeforeUpdate = 1
      Exit For
    Next

End Sub
```

And to use this from your other forms, do it like below :

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

    If Validate_BeforeUpdate(Me) = 1 Then
        Cancel = True
    End If

End Sub
```

This is not a tested code, if you follow this idea, you should be okay to have what you are trying to do.